# Okta-React redirects to okta instead of my site at login

Tags: reactjs, okta, okta-api

Okta-React is redirecting to my okta instance instead of redirecting to my specified route when I log in.

```
import OktaAuth from "@okta/okta-auth-js";

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
  url: process.env.REACT_APP_OKTA_BASE_URL,
  clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
  redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_OKTA_REDIRECT_URI
});


export const login = credentials => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loginReq());
    oktaAuth
      .signIn(credentials)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res));
        dispatch(getGroup(res.user.id));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(loginFailure(err));
      });
  };
};
```

And here I can see the user has successfully logged in and I have a session token, user profile, etc.

But when I call redirect (using okta-react) it redirects to okta-dev instead of localhost:3000/implicit/callback

```
  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.authenticated && !prevProps.authenticated) {
      const auth = await this.props.auth;
      auth.redirect({ sessionToken: this.props.sessionToken });
    }
  }
```

It works perfectly fine in Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome. In Chrome I also have a warning message

> HTTP-Based Public Key Pinning is deprecated. Chrome 69 and later will
>   ignore HPKP response headers. (Host: dev-xxxxxx.oktapreview.com)

Comment: is the route `<Route path="/implicit/callback" component={ImplicitCallback} />` in your routes?

Comment: Yes it is, the reason I believe has to do with  that public key pinning?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js/issues/138) the public key pinning may be a false lead. When it redirects you to your okta-dev page, is it prompting you for login again? If so it could be a 3rd party cookie issue if it's happening in Chrome and not FF. Can you check to see if you are blocking 3rd party cookies?